# To find the maximum possible value of their greatest common divisor $\gcd (a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_7)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, discrete-optimization

The sum of seven distinct positive integers $a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_7$ is $315$. To find the maximum possible value of their greatest common divisor $\gcd (a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_7)$.

---

If they were all equal then $a_i = 45$ and the maximum possible value of their greatest common divisor would have been $45$.

Since they are distinct $\gcd(a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_7) < 45$.

Let $ \gcd(a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_7) = d$. Hence $a_i = db_i$ for some $b_i$ for all $i$.

Since $a_1 + \cdots + a_7 = 315$, we have $d(b_1 +\cdots+ b_7) = 315$ and hence $d$ divides $315$.

Thus $d$ can be any factor of $315$ smaller than $45$.

---

How to proceed after that?

Comment: So...what answer do you get?

Comment: @lulu I got 35 as the answer.

Comment: Well...then you want $35(b_1+\cdots +b_n)=315\implies (b_1+\cdots +b_n)=9$.  But the least number which is the sum of $7$ distinct positive integers is $(1+2+3+4+5+6+7)=28$.

Comment: We have $b_1, b_2, .. b_7$ also distinct. But $315 = 3^2.5.7$. So the possible $b_i$ are $3,5,7,9,15,21,35,45,63$. We cannot pick seven different numbers whose sum will divide $315$. Therefore $d$ must be 1.

Comment: @sku  Well, no.  There is no requirement that $b_i\,|\,315$.  The numbers $\{9,18,27,36,45,54,126\}$ sum to $315$ and they have gcd $9$, for example.

Comment: I messed up. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $d$ divides both $a$ and $b$, then $d$ divides their sum.  By similar reasoning, the max gcd must be a divisor of $315 = 5 \times 7 \times 3^2.$

Further, set $d$ as the gcd.  Then, you must have that

$a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_7$ can be represented by

$(d \times x_1), (d \times x_2), \cdots, (d \times x_7).$

This implies that $x_1, \cdots, x_7$ must be distinct positive integers, such that

$\displaystyle x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_7 = \frac{315}{d}$.

Further, just as you are very limited in your choices for $d$, a factor of $315$, you are similarly limited in your choices for $~\displaystyle \frac{315}{d}.$

Trying to maximize $d$ is equivalent to trying to minimize $~\displaystyle \frac{315}{d}.$

This implies that you are trying to minimize $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_7.$

However, since $x_1, \cdots, x_7$ must all be positive integers, their sum must be $\geq 1 + 2 + \cdots + 7 = 28.$

Then, you want $~\displaystyle \frac{315}{d}$ to be as small as possible, and still be $\geq 28.$

With $315$ being factored by $5 \times 7 \times 3^2,$ it is immediate that $\displaystyle \frac{315}{d}$ can not be an element in $\{28,29,\cdots, 34\}.$

Therefore, $~\displaystyle \frac{315}{d}$ is minimized by setting it to $(35)$.  This implies that $d = 9$, so $(9)$ is the largest possible gcd.

It remains to verify that the equation $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_7 = 35$ 
does have a solution in distinct positive integers.

Since there is the obvious solution of $(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_6, x_7) = (1,2,\cdots, 6, 14)$, the problem is solved.

Comment: @Mike Specifying that $28d \leq 315$ implies that $d \leq 11.$  So, yes, this represents a more elegant approach, that I did not happen to think of.  My approach was to consider that $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_7$ would have to be $~\displaystyle = \frac{315}{d}$, and therefore, would have to be a multiple of either $3,5,$ or $7$.  It was a simple matter to verify that $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_7 = k$, where $k$ is some element in $\{30,33,28\}$ was unworkable.  For example, since $315$ is odd, you can not have $x_1 + \cdots + x_7$ be even.  Similarly, you can't have their sum be a multiple of $11$.

Comment: @Mike Since I saw this at a glance, it was **game over**, so I never had the opportunity to look for the more elegant approach.